# SQL Server shrink log file best practice

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2012

I use `SQL Server 2008R2` and `2012` and have multi database with Full recovery mode (for support cdc and replication). I have below backup plan for these database.

- each Friday I get a full backup.
- each day Except Friday I get a differential backup
- each day between 8:00 to 22:00 every 10 min I Get a transaction log backup

my log file increased to 20GB. and I want to shrink my log file.

what's the best practice for shrink plan log database file.

**Edit**

I use DBCC LogInfo command for visit virtual log file. 
result of this command is below :

```
FileId  FileSize    StartOffset FSeqNo  Status  Parity  CreateLSN
2   2031616 8192    153091  0   128 0
2   2031616 2039808 152944  0   128 0
2   262144  4071424 152915  0   64  146379000000337400143
2   262144  4333568 152916  0   64  146379000000337400143
2   262144  4595712 152917  0   64  146379000000337400143
2   516096  4857856 152918  0   64  146379000000337400143
2   393216  5373952 152903  0   128 146384000000338800478
2   393216  5767168 152904  0   128 146384000000338800478
2   393216  6160384 152905  0   128 146384000000338800478
2   458752  6553600 152906  0   128 146384000000338800478
2   524288  7012352 152907  0   128 146388000000028800472
2   524288  7536640 152908  0   128 146388000000028800472
2   524288  8060928 152909  0   128 146388000000028800472
2   524288  8585216 152910  0   128 146388000000028800472
2   655360  9109504 152911  0   128 146392000000047200118
2   655360  9764864 152912  0   128 146392000000047200118
2   655360  10420224    152913  0   128 146392000000047200118
2   786432  11075584    152914  0   128 146392000000047200118
2   851968  11862016    152919  0   64  146419000000023700103
2   851968  12713984    152920  0   64  146419000000023700103
2   851968  13565952    152921  0   64  146419000000023700103
2   1048576 14417920    152922  0   64  146419000000023700103
2   1114112 15466496    152923  0   64  146423000000167600012
2   1114112 16580608    152924  0   64  146423000000167600012
2   1114112 17694720    152925  0   64  146423000000167600012
2   1310720 18808832    152926  0   64  146423000000167600012
2   1507328 20119552    152927  0   64  146427000000209100022
2   1507328 21626880    152929  0   64  146427000000209100022
2   1507328 23134208    152930  0   64  146427000000209100022
2   1507328 24641536    152931  0   64  146427000000209100022
2   1966080 26148864    152932  0   64  146431000000257900016
2   1966080 28114944    152933  0   64  146431000000257900016
2   1966080 30081024    152934  0   64  146431000000257900016
2   1966080 32047104    152935  0   64  146431000000257900016
2   2555904 34013184    152898  0   128 146435000000336700424
2   2555904 36569088    152899  0   128 146435000000336700424
2   2555904 39124992    152901  0   128 146435000000336700424
2   2555904 41680896    152902  0   128 146435000000336700424
2   3276800 44236800    152936  0   128 146473000000341700024
2   3276800 47513600    152937  0   128 146473000000341700024
2   3276800 50790400    152938  0   128 146473000000341700024
2   3473408 54067200    152897  0   64  146473000000341700024
2   4325376 57540608    152939  0   64  146518000000553000011
2   4325376 61865984    152940  0   64  146518000000553000011
2   4325376 66191360    152941  0   64  146518000000553000011
2   4325376 70516736    152942  0   64  146518000000553000011
2   5570560 74842112    152943  0   64  146522000000736300005
2   5570560 80412672    152945  0   64  146522000000736300005
2   5570560 85983232    152946  0   64  146522000000736300005
2   5767168 91553792    152947  0   64  146522000000736300005
2   7274496 97320960    152948  0   64  146526000001000500002
2   7274496 104595456   152949  0   64  146526000001000500002
2   7274496 111869952   152950  0   64  146526000001000500002
2   7405568 119144448   152952  0   64  146526000001000500002
2   9502720 126550016   152953  0   64  146530000001289300001
2   9502720 136052736   152954  0   64  146530000001289300001
2   9502720 145555456   152888  0   128 146530000001289300001
2   9502720 155058176   152889  0   128 146530000001289300001
2   12320768    164560896   152890  0   128 146534000001656400002
2   12320768    176881664   152891  0   128 146534000001656400002
2   12320768    189202432   152892  0   128 146534000001656400002
2   12451840    201523200   152894  0   128 146534000001656400002
2   16056320    213975040   152895  0   128 146538000002183200001
2   8585216 230031360   152955  0   128 152524000000193600502
2   8585216 238616576   152956  0   128 152524000000193600502
2   8585216 247201792   152957  0   128 152524000000193600502
2   8585216 255787008   152872  0   64  152524000000193600502
2   8585216 264372224   152873  0   64  152524000000193600502
2   8585216 272957440   152874  0   64  152524000000193600502
2   8585216 281542656   152875  0   64  152524000000193600502
2   8912896 290127872   152876  0   64  152524000000193600502
2   11206656    299040768   152877  0   64  152526000001333600502
2   11206656    310247424   152878  0   64  152526000001333600502
2   11206656    321454080   152879  0   64  152526000001333600502
2   11206656    332660736   152881  0   64  152526000001333600502
2   11206656    343867392   152882  0   64  152526000001333600502
2   11206656    355074048   152884  0   64  152526000001333600502
2   11206656    366280704   152885  0   64  152526000001333600502
2   11272192    377487360   152886  0   64  152526000001333600502
2   14548992    388759552   152958  0   64  152608000001573600502
2   14548992    403308544   152959  0   64  152608000001573600502
2   14548992    417857536   152960  0   64  152608000001573600502
2   14548992    432406528   152961  0   64  152608000001573600502
2   14548992    446955520   152962  0   64  152608000001573600502
2   14548992    461504512   152963  0   64  152608000001573600502
2   14548992    476053504   152964  0   64  152608000001573600502
2   14811136    490602496   152965  0   64  152608000001573600502
2   18939904    505413632   152967  0   64  152611000002149600502
2   18939904    524353536   152968  0   64  152611000002149600502
2   18939904    543293440   152970  0   64  152611000002149600502
2   18939904    562233344   152971  0   64  152611000002149600502
2   18939904    581173248   152972  0   64  152611000002149600502
2   18939904    600113152   152973  0   64  152611000002149600502
2   18939904    619053056   152974  0   64  152611000002149600502
2   19070976    637992960   152975  0   64  152611000002149600502
2   24641536    657063936   152976  0   64  152615000001117600502
2   24641536    681705472   152978  0   64  152615000001117600502
2   24641536    706347008   152979  0   64  152615000001117600502
2   24641536    730988544   152980  0   64  152615000001117600502
2   24641536    755630080   152981  0   64  152615000001117600502
2   24641536    780271616   152982  0   64  152615000001117600502
2   24641536    804913152   152852  0   128 152615000001117600502
2   24641536    829554688   152853  0   128 152615000001117600502
2   31981568    854196224   152854  0   128 152619000001417600502
2   31981568    886177792   152855  0   128 152619000001417600502
2   31981568    918159360   152856  0   128 152619000001417600502
2   31981568    950140928   152857  0   128 152619000001417600502
2   31981568    982122496   152859  0   128 152619000001417600502
2   31981568    1014104064  152860  0   128 152619000001417600502
2   31981568    1046085632  152861  0   128 152619000001417600502
2   32440320    1078067200  152862  0   128 152619000001417600502
2   41615360    1110507520  152863  0   128 152624000000385600502
2   41615360    1152122880  152864  0   128 152624000000385600502
2   41615360    1193738240  152865  0   128 152624000000385600502
2   41615360    1235353600  152867  0   128 152624000000385600502
2   41615360    1276968960  152868  0   128 152624000000385600502
2   41615360    1318584320  152869  0   128 152624000000385600502
2   41615360    1360199680  152870  0   128 152624000000385600502
2   41877504    1401815040  152871  0   128 152624000000385600502
2   54132736    1443692544  152983  0   128 152752000004775600060
2   54132736    1497825280  152985  0   128 152752000004775600060
2   54132736    1551958016  152987  0   128 152752000004775600060
2   54132736    1606090752  152988  0   128 152752000004775600060
2   54132736    1660223488  152989  0   128 152752000004775600060
2   54132736    1714356224  152990  0   128 152752000004775600060
2   54132736    1768488960  152992  0   128 152752000004775600060
2   54198272    1822621696  152994  0   128 152752000004775600060
2   70385664    1876819968  152995  0   128 152760000010400600001
2   70385664    1947205632  152997  0   128 152760000010400600001
2   70385664    2017591296  152998  0   128 152760000010400600001
2   70385664    2087976960  152999  0   128 152760000010400600001
2   70385664    2158362624  153000  0   128 152760000010400600001
2   70385664    2228748288  153001  0   128 152760000010400600001
2   70385664    2299133952  153003  0   128 152760000010400600001
2   70385664    2369519616  153005  0   128 152760000010400600001
2   91488256    2439905280  153007  0   128 152768000012875400005
2   91488256    2531393536  153009  0   128 152768000012875400005
2   91488256    2622881792  153011  0   128 152768000012875400005
2   91488256    2714370048  153013  0   128 152768000012875400005
2   91488256    2805858304  153015  0   128 152768000012875400005
2   91488256    2897346560  153016  0   128 152768000012875400005
2   91488256    2988834816  153017  0   128 152768000012875400005
2   91553792    3080323072  153018  0   128 152768000012875400005
2   118947840   3171876864  153019  0   128 152776000017490400003
2   118947840   3290824704  153020  0   128 152776000017490400003
2   118947840   3409772544  153021  0   128 152776000017490400003
2   118947840   3528720384  153022  0   128 152776000017490400003
2   118947840   3647668224  153023  0   128 152776000017490400003
2   118947840   3766616064  153024  0   128 152776000017490400003
2   118947840   3885563904  153025  0   128 152776000017490400003
2   118947840   4004511744  153026  0   128 152776000017490400003
2   77266944    4123459584  153027  0   128 152784000022608500002
2   77266944    4200726528  153028  0   128 152784000022608500002
2   77266944    4277993472  153029  0   128 152784000022608500002
2   77266944    4355260416  153030  0   128 152784000022608500002
2   77266944    4432527360  153031  0   128 152784000022608500002
2   77266944    4509794304  153032  0   128 152784000022608500002
2   77266944    4587061248  153033  0   128 152784000022608500002
2   77266944    4664328192  153034  0   128 152784000022608500002
2   77266944    4741595136  153035  0   128 152784000022608500002
2   77266944    4818862080  153036  0   128 152784000022608500002
2   77266944    4896129024  153037  0   128 152784000022608500002
2   77266944    4973395968  153038  0   128 152784000022608500002
2   77266944    5050662912  153039  0   128 152784000022608500002
2   77266944    5127929856  153040  0   128 152784000022608500002
2   77266944    5205196800  153041  0   128 152784000022608500002
2   78053376    5282463744  153042  0   128 152784000022608500002
2   100466688   5360517120  153043  0   128 152800000015038900006
2   100466688   5460983808  153044  0   128 152800000015038900006
2   100466688   5561450496  153045  0   128 152800000015038900006
2   100466688   5661917184  153046  0   128 152800000015038900006
2   100466688   5762383872  153047  0   128 152800000015038900006
2   100466688   5862850560  153048  0   128 152800000015038900006
2   100466688   5963317248  153049  0   128 152800000015038900006
2   100466688   6063783936  153050  0   128 152800000015038900006
2   100466688   6164250624  153051  0   128 152800000015038900006
2   100466688   6264717312  153052  0   128 152800000015038900006
2   100466688   6365184000  153053  0   128 152800000015038900006
2   100466688   6465650688  153054  0   128 152800000015038900006
2   100466688   6566117376  153055  0   128 152800000015038900006
2   100466688   6666584064  153056  0   128 152800000015038900006
2   100466688   6767050752  153057  0   128 152800000015038900006
2   101187584   6867517440  153058  0   128 152800000015038900006
2   130613248   6968705024  153059  0   128 152816000019449900004
2   130613248   7099318272  153060  0   128 152816000019449900004
2   130613248   7229931520  153061  0   128 152816000019449900004
2   130613248   7360544768  153062  0   128 152816000019449900004
2   130613248   7491158016  153063  0   128 152816000019449900004
2   130613248   7621771264  153064  0   128 152816000019449900004
2   130613248   7752384512  153065  0   128 152816000019449900004
2   130613248   7882997760  153066  0   128 152816000019449900004
2   130613248   8013611008  153068  0   128 152816000019449900004
2   130613248   8144224256  153069  0   128 152816000019449900004
2   130613248   8274837504  153070  0   128 152816000019449900004
2   130613248   8405450752  153071  0   128 152816000019449900004
2   130613248   8536064000  153072  0   128 152816000019449900004
2   130613248   8666677248  153073  0   128 152816000019449900004
2   130613248   8797290496  153074  0   128 152816000019449900004
2   131465216   8927903744  153076  0   128 152816000019449900004
2   169803776   9059368960  153077  0   128 152832000025629200065
2   169803776   9229172736  153078  0   128 152832000025629200065
2   169803776   9398976512  153079  0   128 152832000025629200065
2   169803776   9568780288  153080  0   128 152832000025629200065
2   169803776   9738584064  153081  0   128 152832000025629200065
2   169803776   9908387840  153082  0   128 152832000025629200065
2   169803776   10078191616 153084  0   128 152832000025629200065
2   169803776   10247995392 153086  0   128 152832000025629200065
2   169803776   10417799168 153088  0   128 152832000025629200065
2   169803776   10587602944 153090  0   128 152832000025629200065
2   169803776   10757406720 153092  2   128 152832000025629200065
2   169803776   10927210496 152845  0   64  152832000025629200065
2   169803776   11097014272 152846  0   64  152832000025629200065
2   169803776   11266818048 152847  0   64  152832000025629200065
2   169803776   11436621824 152848  0   64  152832000025629200065
2   170786816   11606425600 152850  0   64  152832000025629200065
```

status of most virtual file is 0. and I expect that SQL Server use virtual file with status 0 instead of create a new virtual file.

**EDIT 2**

I Change Autogrowth of my database to 250MB and initial size to 2000MB. But the size of my database grow to 5000MB in 12 hour. The result of `DBCC Loginfo` command is below.

How can I control size of my database log file.

```
FileId  FileSize    StartOffset FSeqNo  Status  Parity  CreateLSN
2   2031616 8192    154016  0   128 0
2   2031616 2039808 154017  0   128 0
2   262144  4071424 153848  0   128 146379000000337400143
2   262144  4333568 153849  0   128 146379000000337400143
2   262144  4595712 153850  0   128 146379000000337400143
2   516096  4857856 153851  0   128 146379000000337400143
2   393216  5373952 153836  0   64  146384000000338800478
2   393216  5767168 153837  0   64  146384000000338800478
2   393216  6160384 153838  0   64  146384000000338800478
2   458752  6553600 153839  0   64  146384000000338800478
2   524288  7012352 153840  0   64  146388000000028800472
2   524288  7536640 153841  0   64  146388000000028800472
2   524288  8060928 153842  0   64  146388000000028800472
2   524288  8585216 153843  0   64  146388000000028800472
2   655360  9109504 153844  0   64  146392000000047200118
2   655360  9764864 153845  0   64  146392000000047200118
2   655360  10420224    153846  0   64  146392000000047200118
2   786432  11075584    153847  0   64  146392000000047200118
2   851968  11862016    153852  0   128 146419000000023700103
2   851968  12713984    153853  0   128 146419000000023700103
2   851968  13565952    153854  0   128 146419000000023700103
2   1048576 14417920    153855  0   128 146419000000023700103
2   1114112 15466496    153856  0   128 146423000000167600012
2   1114112 16580608    153857  0   128 146423000000167600012
2   1114112 17694720    153858  0   128 146423000000167600012
2   1310720 18808832    153859  0   128 146423000000167600012
2   1507328 20119552    153860  0   128 146427000000209100022
2   1507328 21626880    153861  0   128 146427000000209100022
2   1507328 23134208    153862  0   128 146427000000209100022
2   1507328 24641536    153863  0   128 146427000000209100022
2   1966080 26148864    153864  0   128 146431000000257900016
2   1966080 28114944    153865  0   128 146431000000257900016
2   1966080 30081024    153866  0   128 146431000000257900016
2   1966080 32047104    153867  0   128 146431000000257900016
2   2555904 34013184    153832  0   64  146435000000336700424
2   2555904 36569088    153833  0   64  146435000000336700424
2   2555904 39124992    153834  0   64  146435000000336700424
2   2555904 41680896    153835  0   64  146435000000336700424
2   3276800 44236800    153868  0   64  146473000000341700024
2   3276800 47513600    153869  0   64  146473000000341700024
2   3276800 50790400    153870  0   64  146473000000341700024
2   3473408 54067200    153831  0   128 146473000000341700024
2   4325376 57540608    153871  0   128 146518000000553000011
2   4325376 61865984    153872  0   128 146518000000553000011
2   4325376 66191360    153873  0   128 146518000000553000011
2   4325376 70516736    153874  0   128 146518000000553000011
2   5570560 74842112    153875  0   128 146522000000736300005
2   5570560 80412672    153876  0   128 146522000000736300005
2   5570560 85983232    153877  0   128 146522000000736300005
2   5767168 91553792    153878  0   128 146522000000736300005
2   7274496 97320960    153879  0   128 146526000001000500002
2   7274496 104595456   153880  0   128 146526000001000500002
2   7274496 111869952   153881  0   128 146526000001000500002
2   7405568 119144448   153882  0   128 146526000001000500002
2   9502720 126550016   153883  0   128 146530000001289300001
2   9502720 136052736   153884  0   128 146530000001289300001
2   9502720 145555456   153824  0   64  146530000001289300001
2   9502720 155058176   153825  0   64  146530000001289300001
2   12320768    164560896   153826  0   64  146534000001656400002
2   12320768    176881664   153827  0   64  146534000001656400002
2   12320768    189202432   153828  0   64  146534000001656400002
2   12451840    201523200   153829  0   64  146534000001656400002
2   16056320    213975040   153830  0   64  146538000002183200001
2   8585216 230031360   153885  0   64  152524000000193600502
2   8585216 238616576   153886  0   64  152524000000193600502
2   8585216 247201792   153887  0   64  152524000000193600502
2   8585216 255787008   154003  0   64  152524000000193600502
2   8585216 264372224   154004  0   64  152524000000193600502
2   8585216 272957440   154005  0   64  152524000000193600502
2   8585216 281542656   154006  0   64  152524000000193600502
2   8912896 290127872   154007  0   64  152524000000193600502
2   11206656    299040768   153816  0   128 152526000001333600502
2   11206656    310247424   153817  0   128 152526000001333600502
2   11206656    321454080   153818  0   128 152526000001333600502
2   11206656    332660736   153819  0   128 152526000001333600502
2   11206656    343867392   153820  0   128 152526000001333600502
2   11206656    355074048   153821  0   128 152526000001333600502
2   11206656    366280704   153822  0   128 152526000001333600502
2   11272192    377487360   153823  0   128 152526000001333600502
2   14548992    388759552   153888  0   128 152608000001573600502
2   14548992    403308544   153889  0   128 152608000001573600502
2   14548992    417857536   153890  0   128 152608000001573600502
2   14548992    432406528   153891  0   128 152608000001573600502
2   14548992    446955520   153892  0   128 152608000001573600502
2   14548992    461504512   153893  0   128 152608000001573600502
2   14548992    476053504   153894  0   128 152608000001573600502
2   14811136    490602496   153895  0   128 152608000001573600502
2   18939904    505413632   153896  0   128 152611000002149600502
2   18939904    524353536   153897  0   128 152611000002149600502
2   18939904    543293440   153988  0   128 152611000002149600502
2   18939904    562233344   153989  0   128 152611000002149600502
2   18939904    581173248   153990  0   128 152611000002149600502
2   18939904    600113152   153991  0   128 152611000002149600502
2   18939904    619053056   153992  0   128 152611000002149600502
2   19070976    637992960   153993  0   128 152611000002149600502
2   24641536    657063936   153994  0   128 152615000001117600502
2   24641536    681705472   153995  0   128 152615000001117600502
2   24641536    706347008   153996  0   128 152615000001117600502
2   24641536    730988544   153997  0   128 152615000001117600502
2   24641536    755630080   153998  0   128 152615000001117600502
2   24641536    780271616   153999  0   128 152615000001117600502
2   24641536    804913152   154000  0   128 152615000001117600502
2   24641536    829554688   154001  0   128 152615000001117600502
2   31981568    854196224   154002  0   128 152619000001417600502
2   75628544    886177792   154008  0   64  153324000000173800025
2   75628544    961806336   154009  0   64  153324000000173800025
2   75628544    1037434880  154010  0   64  153324000000173800025
2   75628544    1113063424  154011  0   64  153324000000173800025
2   75628544    1188691968  154012  0   64  153324000000173800025
2   75628544    1264320512  154013  0   64  153324000000173800025
2   75628544    1339949056  154014  0   64  153324000000173800025
2   75628544    1415577600  154015  0   64  153324000000173800025
2   75628544    1491206144  154018  2   64  153324000000173800025
2   75628544    1566834688  153809  0   128 153324000000173800025
2   75628544    1642463232  153810  0   128 153324000000173800025
2   75628544    1718091776  153811  0   128 153324000000173800025
2   75628544    1793720320  153812  0   128 153324000000173800025
2   75628544    1869348864  153813  0   128 153324000000173800025
2   75628544    1944977408  153814  0   128 153324000000173800025
2   76546048    2020605952  153815  0   128 153324000000173800025
2   32768000    2097152000  153898  0   64  153897000003656100039
2   32768000    2129920000  153899  0   64  153897000003656100039
2   32768000    2162688000  153900  0   64  153897000003656100039
2   32768000    2195456000  153901  0   64  153897000003656100039
2   32768000    2228224000  153902  0   64  153897000003656100039
2   32768000    2260992000  153903  0   64  153897000003656100039
2   32768000    2293760000  153904  0   64  153897000003656100039
2   32768000    2326528000  153905  0   64  153897000003656100039
2   32768000    2359296000  153906  0   64  153905000006350900482
2   32768000    2392064000  153907  0   64  153905000006350900482
2   32768000    2424832000  153908  0   64  153905000006350900482
2   32768000    2457600000  153909  0   64  153905000006350900482
2   32768000    2490368000  153910  0   64  153905000006350900482
2   32768000    2523136000  153911  0   64  153905000006350900482
2   32768000    2555904000  153912  0   64  153905000006350900482
2   32768000    2588672000  153913  0   64  153905000006350900482
2   32768000    2621440000  153914  0   64  153913000006355000052
2   32768000    2654208000  153915  0   64  153913000006355000052
2   32768000    2686976000  153916  0   64  153913000006355000052
2   32768000    2719744000  153917  0   64  153913000006355000052
2   32768000    2752512000  153918  0   64  153913000006355000052
2   32768000    2785280000  153919  0   64  153913000006355000052
2   32768000    2818048000  153920  0   64  153913000006355000052
2   32768000    2850816000  153921  0   64  153913000006355000052
2   32768000    2883584000  153922  0   64  153921000006354400052
2   32768000    2916352000  153923  0   64  153921000006354400052
2   32768000    2949120000  153924  0   64  153921000006354400052
2   32768000    2981888000  153925  0   64  153921000006354400052
2   32768000    3014656000  153926  0   64  153921000006354400052
2   32768000    3047424000  153927  0   64  153921000006354400052
2   32768000    3080192000  153928  0   64  153921000006354400052
2   32768000    3112960000  153929  0   64  153921000006354400052
2   32768000    3145728000  153930  0   64  153929000006352000078
2   32768000    3178496000  153931  0   64  153929000006352000078
2   32768000    3211264000  153932  0   64  153929000006352000078
2   32768000    3244032000  153933  0   64  153929000006352000078
2   32768000    3276800000  153934  0   64  153929000006352000078
2   32768000    3309568000  153935  0   64  153929000006352000078
2   32768000    3342336000  153936  0   64  153929000006352000078
2   32768000    3375104000  153937  0   64  153929000006352000078
2   32768000    3407872000  153938  0   64  153937000006357700039
2   32768000    3440640000  153939  0   64  153937000006357700039
2   32768000    3473408000  153940  0   64  153937000006357700039
2   32768000    3506176000  153941  0   64  153937000006357700039
2   32768000    3538944000  153942  0   64  153937000006357700039
2   32768000    3571712000  153943  0   64  153937000006357700039
2   32768000    3604480000  153944  0   64  153937000006357700039
2   32768000    3637248000  153945  0   64  153937000006357700039
2   32768000    3670016000  153946  0   64  153945000006355900052
2   32768000    3702784000  153947  0   64  153945000006355900052
2   32768000    3735552000  153948  0   64  153945000006355900052
2   32768000    3768320000  153949  0   64  153945000006355900052
2   32768000    3801088000  153950  0   64  153945000006355900052
2   32768000    3833856000  153951  0   64  153945000006355900052
2   32768000    3866624000  153952  0   64  153945000006355900052
2   32768000    3899392000  153953  0   64  153945000006355900052
2   32768000    3932160000  153954  0   64  153953000006355700039
2   32768000    3964928000  153955  0   64  153953000006355700039
2   32768000    3997696000  153956  0   64  153953000006355700039
2   32768000    4030464000  153957  0   64  153953000006355700039
2   32768000    4063232000  153958  0   64  153953000006355700039
2   32768000    4096000000  153959  0   64  153953000006355700039
2   32768000    4128768000  153960  0   64  153953000006355700039
2   32768000    4161536000  153961  0   64  153953000006355700039
2   32768000    4194304000  153962  0   64  153961000006355800049
2   32768000    4227072000  153963  0   64  153961000006355800049
2   32768000    4259840000  153964  0   64  153961000006355800049
2   32768000    4292608000  153965  0   64  153961000006355800049
2   32768000    4325376000  153966  0   64  153961000006355800049
2   32768000    4358144000  153967  0   64  153961000006355800049
2   32768000    4390912000  153968  0   64  153961000006355800049
2   32768000    4423680000  153969  0   64  153961000006355800049
2   32768000    4456448000  153970  0   64  153969000006355300063
2   32768000    4489216000  153971  0   64  153969000006355300063
2   32768000    4521984000  153972  0   64  153969000006355300063
2   32768000    4554752000  153973  0   64  153969000006355300063
2   32768000    4587520000  153974  0   64  153969000006355300063
2   32768000    4620288000  153975  0   64  153969000006355300063
2   32768000    4653056000  153976  0   64  153969000006355300063
2   32768000    4685824000  153977  0   64  153969000006355300063
2   32768000    4718592000  153978  0   64  153977000006350000039
2   32768000    4751360000  153979  0   64  153977000006350000039
2   32768000    4784128000  153980  0   64  153977000006350000039
2   32768000    4816896000  153981  0   64  153977000006350000039
2   32768000    4849664000  153982  0   64  153977000006350000039
2   32768000    4882432000  153985  0   64  153977000006350000039
2   32768000    4915200000  153986  0   64  153977000006350000039
2   32768000    4947968000  153987  0   64  153977000006350000039
```

thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

The best practice is not to shrink the log.

There was a reason why the log grew, and it will probably happen again, so why risk the autogrowths? They take time (BTW make sure the autogrowth is in MBs, not in percent).

The log is 20 GB; with autogrowth 30% it means that the the las time it grew it was 5 GB. To allocate 5 GB and overwrite it with 0s, it must have taken some time.

Monitor the size of the log and the internal usage over time to see how large the log size shoud be, and then if it needs shrinking, use `DBCC SHRINKFILE` to size it accordingly. Always leave some additional space in it.

Comment: the autogrowth of my database is 30 percent. please see my edit.

Comment: Ouch. It is empty but it's so fragmented. The fragmentation is caused by setting autogrowth to percent instead of MBs. OK, shrink the log as much as you can to get rid of VLFs and then set it to a large enough size with `ALTER DATABASE`. See here: https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/database-administration/sql-server-transaction-log-fragmentation-a-primer/

Comment: You didn't follow advice from my answer (even unchecked it!), you didn't take some time to monitor the usage, and consequently made the log file too small again. As for the reason it grew, it probably needs to be that large; can't say why, it looks from loginfo like a couple of large transactions happened, maybe regular index rebuilds or some data load operation.